# Logging the x and y position of a object in After Effects Script

Tags: after-effects

Im trying to do a simple script in After Effects for a tracking system im developing.

Basicaly I need to print the x and y position of a object in a animation in a file. Something like x,y and timestamp.

Like:

120;130;1000;  --- 120 x, 130 y and 1000 ms
130;160;2000;  --- 130 x, 160 y and 2000 ms

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can get the position of an object by accessing the position property.

See the [After Effects Scripting Guide](https://blogs.adobe.com/aftereffects/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf)

```
var currTime = 1; // calculated in seconds
var preExpression = true;
var xy = app.project.item(index).layer(index).transform.position.valueAtTime(currTime, preExpression); // returns an array of 2 or 3 [x,y,z]
```

To write your data to file you can use this:

```
var randomname = Number(new Date());
var filepath = "~/Desktop/" + randomname + ".txt";
var outfile = File(filepath);
outfile.open('a');
if (outfile !== '') {
  outfile.writeln("Hello I'm an appended line!");
  outfile.close();
}
```

Take a look into the Help Section of the ExtendScript Toolkit and maybe my [wiki](https://github.com/fabiantheblind/extendscript/wiki).

Comment: I think i did it, no?